# "View all questions" list cut off on iPhone 4S

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, iphone

When I go to one of my per-site profiles, and tap 'All X posts' it gives me a search list, where the screen height appears to be calculated wrong.

The below screenshot is as far down as I can scroll - the bottom half of the last question, and the scroll bar are off the bottom of the screen. Interestingly, the bug isn't present if I do the same search from the main site search.

iPhone 4S, iOS 8.2, Beta App 1.2.2.184.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great catch!

We had recently done some refactoring to improve Voice Over accessibility on all the search views. This had the unfortunate side-effect that some height calculations got out of whack when presenting this view.

This will be fixed in **Beta version 1.2.2.186.**

Comment: But... the current version is 1.2.2.185 :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard looks like it's another build issue on our end. The download page is showing current is 184, but the app is showing 185. Will take a look.

Comment: Yeah, Brian said it's a known issue so I didn't bother to mention it. :)

Comment: Completely unrelated, but just caught me here - why is upvote + accept rate limited? (And cheers for the speedy fix!)